# (new to haskell) if statment generating parse error

Tags: haskell

I want the function to create a list of a tuple if the condition applies but it doesnt seem to be working. (I'm new to haskell)

```hs
exist'z s = [ y | y <- s, toLower (y) =='z' ]
freq'z s =  if (exsit'z s /= "") then [( 'z', length (exist'z s ))]
```

Comment: In Haskell, you can't have an `if` expression without the `else` part.

Comment: In the second line you wrote `exsit'z` instead of `exist'z`.

Answer (score 4):

In Haskell, `if` clauses are expressions. That implies that they need to always evaluate to a value, and also to have a definite type. More specifically, `if` clauses without an `else` are syntax errors. Also, the `then` and `else` cases need to have the same type.

In your case, you can have a function create a list of tuples if the condition applies, but for the function to be well-typed, that function would need to return a list of tuples regardless. Why you want to return a list of tuples I'm not sure, since the way you wrote it it will always be a singleton in the `then` case. You can append `else []` and make it work, but perhaps a more suitable type for this would be `Maybe`:

```
exist'z :: String -> String
exist'z s = [ y | y <- s, toLower y =='z' ]

freq'z :: String -> Maybe (Char, Int)
freq'z s =  if (exist'z s /= "") then Just ( 'z', length (exist'z s )) else Nothing
```